# Повторное использование вычисленного MAX()

Tags: max, mysql

Здравствуйте, есть некоторый жуткий запрос:

```
SELECT 
 order.id as id,
CASE 
WHEN ((MAX(order_item_log.date) IS NOT NULL) AND (MAX(mail_history.date) IS NULL)) 
THEN MAX(order_item_log.date)

WHEN ((MAX(mail_history.date) IS NOT NULL) AND (MAX(order_item_log.date) IS NULL)) 
THEN MAX(mail_history.date)

WHEN MAX(order_item_log.date) >= MAX(mail_history.date) 
THEN MAX(order_item_log.date)

WHEN MAX(order_item_log.date) < MAX(mail_history.date) 
THEN MAX(mail_history.date)
END
as date_change ....
```

можно ли как-то использовать вычисленное MAX() повторно, заранее спасибо

Comment: а не проще выбрать все три поля и уже в коде решить что нужнее?

Comment: а вы посмотрите explain запроса, что-то мне подсказывает что оно каждый max один раз и выполнит.

Еще может быть можно переделать в IFNULL(IFNULL(IFNULL(),),)

Comment: да он и так коштовный получается, если без всех этих преобразований с Max(), если просто три поля выбрать что-то около 4 c. а если со всеми Max()  увеличивается до 16 с.

Comment: a это чем нибудь отличается от `SELECT GREATEST(MAX(order_item_log.date),MAX(mail_history.date)) as date_change` ? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4579d/2

Comment: Если Вы переживаете за производительность- MySQL не будет каждый раз вычислять значение. Оно будет вычислено лишь единожды.

Answer (score 1):

сделайте хранимую процедуру, возвращающую искомое значение.